# How to scroll to the top of a scrollview when a new page in a webview is loaded

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview set inside a scrollview. When I initially scroll down to the bottom of the screen and click a link inside the webview the page that loads is visible in the middle of the page. How can I auto scroll to the top of my scrollview. I have googled but no answers. iOS does this automatically but android does not as far as I have seen. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I set a smoothscroll(0,0) but it scrolls to the top before it moves to the next page. Maybe this is all i can work with. any other solutions would be appreciated.

```
if(isConnectingToInternet()){
        WebProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextNoInternet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        WebProducts.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        WebProducts.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebProducts.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        WebProducts.loadUrl("http://www.healthfitnessenergy.com/productpages/products.php");
    }
    else{
        WebProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TextNoInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    WebProducts.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            ScrollView1.smoothScrollTo(0,0);
            return false;
        }
    });

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/product_qs2_products"
        style="@style/Bold_Black_20" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvProducts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </WebView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ifnointernet"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Product Menu will be available when cell/wifi service is available"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`setVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)) method inside `OnPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()` to do the trick. Basically remove the existing view.

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will "scrollview.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);" in some listener help you?

Comment: the code listed above is what i have to handle the webview to keep links inside the app. not sure how to establish listeners for buttons on a webpage to work inside the app.

Comment: What if make it in "onPageFinished" of your WebViewClient? This will scroll, when the page finished loading. Or I don't get your goal?

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin M your issue can be solve by overriding the two methods onPageStarted and onPageFinished as answered by @Htet Will.
And your other issue "not sure how to establish listeners for buttons on a webpage to work inside the app" can be solve by JS Bridge.As in ios you must know the concept of js bridging ,it is similar in android also.

1st -you have to enable you webview for javascript interface.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

2nd - Make an javascript interface

```
@Keep
    private class JavaScriptInterface {

        private JavaScriptInterface() {
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void methodName(){

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do what you want in your java class
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

3rd - Assign the JavaScriptInterface to webview

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "jsSolutionInterface");
```

4th - In html button add a on click method lets say open().In the method called open you can call the javascript interface method .Example of the js method:

```
function open()
{jsSolutionInterface.methodName();}
```

In this way you can bridge  js and java methods.Hope this will help you.